# spacing value between value in x-axis matplotlib using python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a FPR and TPR plot. In here I want to ask how to arangge spacing value between the x-axis. My code is following below:

```
  In [85]:

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), dpi=80)
    ax.plot(x_iter1_TF , y_iter1_TF, label='Iter1', marker='o')
    ax.plot(x_iter5_TF, y_iter5_TF ,label='Iter5',  marker='v')
    ax.plot(x_iter10_TF, y_iter10_TF , label='Iter10',  marker='x')
    ax.plot(x_iter25_TF, y_iter25_TF , label='Iter20',  marker='+')
    ax.plot(x_iter50_TF, y_iter50_TF , label='Iter50',marker='D')
    ax.legend(loc=1); # upper left corner
    ax.set_xlabel('FPR')
    ax.set_ylabel('TPR')
    ax.set_xlim([0,1, 0.001])
    ax.set_ylim([0,1, 0.001])
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-85-87b9ef379a9b> in <module>()
          8 ax.set_xlabel('FPR')
          9 ax.set_ylabel('TPR')
    ---> 10 ax.set_xlim([0,1, 0.001])
         11 ax.set_ylim([0,1, 0.001])

    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.pyc in set_xlim(self, left, right, emit, auto, **kw)
       2524 
       2525         if right is None and iterable(left):
    -> 2526             left, right = left
       2527 
       2528         self._process_unit_info(xdata=(left, right))

    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

[image]

In here I used ax.set_xlim([0,1, 0.001]) where 0.001 is spacing value between x-axis. Unfortunately, i faced an error. I think i did the wrong way to set those thing

Comment: `set_xlim` does not accept a "step" parameter. See the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, `set_xlim` does not accept a "step" parameter. Also, the method I think you want is `set_xticks`, which can be used as follows:

```
In [13]: import numpy as np
    ...: ticks = np.arange(0, 2, 0.1)
    ...: ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ...: fig
```

And gives the following result:

[image]